# how to convert pfCashedNumer to int?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

after a core data request, i get a dictionary, which one value of this is the number of entry, if i try to print the value with:

```
NSLog(@"number of entry %@",[dic valueForKey:@"count"]);
```

i get the right result, like:

```
number of entry 4
```

ok, if i try to convert this number into an int using this:

```
         int numberForActualCoordinate = (int)[dic valueForKey:@"count"];
         NSLog(@"value %i",numberForActualCoordinate);
```

i get this result

```
value 5754900
```

what the hell is wrong, if i try to print the class of the value into a dictionary i get this:

```
  NSLog(@"class %@",[[dic valueForKey:@"count"] class]);
```

result:

```
class _PFCachedNumber
```

So the question is, how can i convert a _PFCachedNumber value into an int?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `dic` is a `NSDictionary` and the value of count is a `NSNumber`:
It is not a number, it is a `NSNumber` object so simple casting will not work. Instead use the method `intValue`.

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"count":@1};
int numberForActualCoordinate = [[dic valueForKey:@"count"] intValue];
NSLog(@"value %i",numberForActualCoordinate);
```

NSLog output:

> value 1

or using literals:

```
int numberForActualCoordinate = [dic[@"count"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a subclass of [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Try: `[[dic valueForKey:@"count"] integerValue]` and then you can print it with a `%ld` like you would with a long.